# Entity Relations: Inheritance, Composition, Interface, or Mixed Set?

Tags: entity-relationship

I'm really struggling with this scenario :

I have two entities: `Person` and `Company`

both share common properties so I have a base abstract class `Contact`

Now I have another entity called `Supplier` this can be either a `Company` or a `Person`

And I just don't know how to set up this scenario.

What I have so far is :

```
public abstract class Contact {
    public abstract string DisplayName { get; }
    ...
}
public class Person : Contact {
    public override string DisplayName { ... }
    public string SomePersonProperty { get; set; }
    ...
}
public class Company : Contact {
    public override string DisplayName {...}
    public string SomeCompanyProperty { get; set; }
    ...
}
public class Supplier {
    public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
    ...
     // how can I make this being either a Person or a Company ?
}
```

The use for this will be:

- Get Suppliers that are Persons
- Get Suppliers that are Companies
- Get all Suppliers

With the object Supplier ideally I want to access the particular properties either of Company or Person.

Is that even possible ? Where's the flaw in the design (pretty sure there's at least one).

From my thinking:

- `Person` **is** a `Contact`
- `Company` **is** a `Contact`
- `Supplier` **is** either a `Person` **or** a `Company`
- `Person` **can** be a `Supplier`
- `Company` **can** be a `Supplier`
- `Supplier` **cannot** be a `Person` **and** a `Company`

I'm trying to implement this in C# Entity Framework Code First but I think the question is not close to those technologies.

**UPDATE** : I came up with this but I'm not sure if ok or messy. Comments are welcome!

```
public abstract class Supplier  {
    public int SupplierId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
    ...
}

public abstract class Supplier<T> : Supplier where T : Contact {
    public T Contact { get; set; }
}

public class SupplierPerson : Supplier<Person> {}
public class SupplierCompany : Supplier<Company> {}
```

not sure what type of Database Schema this will generate...

Comment: I think that you need Haskel. If you keep using Java, make Company and Person implementing Supplier.

Comment: Doesn't that implies that a Company IS a Supplier instead of CAN BE a Supplier ?

Comment: Why dont you get rid of Person and Company classes and just use Contact with a common set of properties and an additional property which specifies what type of contact a specific object is (Person or Company), that way the Contact class can easily become the base for your Supplier class. You would not have issues with entity framework design if you do it this way.

Comment: @stripthesoul because company and person while do have common properties and navigations are and need to be quite different.

Comment: it's c# not java. anyways, I don't mind having a bool property. Still I don't see how this fits in. And btw, Company and Person while have common properties (address, email, phone, tax id, etc), they have differences. Like a Middle Name (Person), Employees (Company), Childs (Person), Brothers (Person), Subsidiary (Company), Stock Symbol (Company), Profession (Person), Curriculum (Person) and so on.

Comment: Your new design would create two separate Supplier tables instead of one.

Answer (score 0):

Make your Person and Company implementing Supplier interface. Supplier extends the Contact interface. Now, you can include the Persons and Companies into your lists of suppliers

```
class Institution {
  Supplier supplier; // refers either Person or Company
```

This is natural implementation and, therefore, has an advantage that you do not need to allocate extra space per object to store the category of referred supplier. I suppose that this solution is not acceptable [OOP is considered evil ourdays](http://valjok.blogspot.com/2013/01/java-oop-is-sux-from-very-beginning.html).